# Linux (Fedora) scheduler that supports repeat so often

Tags: scheduled-tasks, cron, scheduler

Not that I have much experience with crontab but I understand it is not possible to schedule jobs to run every X time units (e.g. run every 30 min) but the exec times must be specific.

Does anyone know of a scheduler that supports this functionality and can run out of a command in the background, better yet out of systemd as a service?  And that is free, of course (so no Autosys and such).

e.g. Ktimer on Fedora can do repeats but it is not a service, does not have CL, and the app actually must be open in order to run tasks.  so it doesn't cut it...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, it can be done via crontab:

0,20,40 * * * *

runs it every 20 min